# Custom uitableviewcell displaying images in alternate cell

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, load, cell, lazy-evaluation

Okay, so after checking a lot of SO answers, I am posting this.
I am trying to make a custom a uitableviewCell in which i have one uiimageview and uilabel.
The problem is when i load cells, it loads alternate images in uitableview only, also loads correct data for uilabel for each cell. 
**It should load images on all the cells And sometimes misplaces the images in wrong cells also**

Here is what i am doing...

Step 1:

```
#define kActivityCell @"ActivityCell"
```

Step 2:

```
[self.feedTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:kActivityCell bundle:nil]
         forCellReuseIdentifier:kActivityCell];
```

Step 3:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    // format for feeds
    NSLog(@"row no: %d",indexPath.row);

    ActivityCell *activityCell = (ActivityCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kActivityCell forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //selection color
    UIView *selectionColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
    selectionColor.backgroundColor = [GeneralUtils colorWithString:kTableSelectionHEX];
    activityCell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionColor;


    [activityCell listOfLikeSetting];

    ZDUser *newObject = [likeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    activityCell.nameAndDesc.text = newObject.display_name;
    activityCell.nameAndDesc.font = [GeneralUtils FontSettingBold13];
    activityCell.objectID = newObject.userID;
    activityCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    // this method is from AFNetworking Lib
    [activityCell.photoLeft setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:newObject.avatar]];

    // this is my own method to cache images, but i am not using it right now. 
    // [activityCell.photoLeft setProfileImageFor:newObject.avatar];

    return activityCell;
}
```

I have created a separate class for ActivityCell and xib is there in which i have made the connections properly for iboutlet uiimageview photoleft

As per now, i am clueless why its happening anybody pls share your thoughts...
here are some of the links which i have read , but it didn't help me.

[Lazy load images in UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531482/lazy-load-images-in-uitableviewcell)

[UIImageView not showing up in custom UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044231/uiimageview-not-showing-up-in-custom-uitableviewcell)

[UITableViewCell load images and reused cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9187172/uitableviewcell-load-images-and-reused-cells?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solved now, it was because of using the same cell at many places and customising according to needs so there was some internal issue. 
I have now created a new class for it and it works fine.

Thanks
Sumit